# Load Disqus comments on blogger post using jquery colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blogger, disqus

I am working on a **blogger** site with **Disqus** comments on and I am trying to make it load comments into jquery **colorbox**.

I have two scripts at the top of `</body>` tag that loading some Disqus `js` files. The first script loads the `count.js` and the second one loads the `embed.js`.

**HTML**

```
<i class='fa fa-comment'/>
<a class='show-comments'>
    <span class="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-url='***'>Counting...</span>
</a>
<div id='disqus_thread'/>
```

**Call of count.js**

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//***.disqus.com/count.js" async='async'></script>
```

**Call of embed.js**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.show-comments').on('click', function(){
            var disqus_shortname = '***'; // Replace this value with *your* username.

            // ajax request to load the disqus javascript
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
                dataType: "script",
                cache: true
            });
            // hide the button once comments load
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });     
</script>
```

So, after all, I also want when user click on `show-comments` link to load Disqus comments into colorobox!!!

I tried some stuff like add `inline` class to the link and point `href` to `#comments` id of Disqus comments body, but nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Here is a working test http://jsfiddle.net/nate/udET6/ (content seems swedish for me)

Comment: It just loads disqus comments... My question is how can I load it into a jquery colorbox?